# Open new window isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

What I'm trying to do is open a new window in every item in table display. But when I tried to click isn't working and there's an SyntaxError: syntax error in console. Why is that?

```
 echo"  <tr class='record'>
            <td>".$i++."</td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick='window.open('edit.php?pn=".$row['id']."', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=200'); return false;'><img src='images/edit.png'></a></td>
            <td align='center'><a href='#' name='".$row['id']."' class='delbutton'><img src='images/del.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Delete'></a></td>";
```

Comment: It's not common to single quote HTML attributes. Use backslashes for your attributes and you should be fine. E.g. `class=\"record\"`

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks are getting mixed up in the `onclick` attribute. Rewrite the code to something like:

```
 echo"  <tr class='record'>
            <td>".$i++."</td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('edit.php?pn=".$row['id']."', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=200'); return false;\"><img src='images/edit.png'></a></td>
            <td align='center'><a href='#' name='".$row['id']."' class='delbutton'><img src='images/del.png' border='0' width='10' height='10' title='Delete'></a></td>";
```